# Powershell dte create project of targeting platform

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2017, envdte

```
PM> $dte.Solution.Create("C:\Projects\test\", "test.sln")
PM> $t = $dte.Solution.GetProjectTemplate("ConsoleApplication.zip", "CSharp" )
PM> $dte.Solution.AddFromTemplate($t, "C:\Projects\test\proj\", "New CSharp Console Project", $false)
```

I'm using VS 2017. This creates a solution and a project. The project is targeting .NET Core. How to change this line:

```
PM> $t = $dte.Solution.GetProjectTemplate("ConsoleApplication.zip", "CSharp" )
```

in order to be able to target previous .NET Version - 4.6/4.7

Is there a command to see the available project templates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The VS2017 SDK documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte80.solution2.getprojecttemplate?view=visualstudiosdk-2017) suggests that you should be able to pass in a `FrameworkVersion` parameter as part of the template name:

> If a template has a RequiredFrameworkVersion element higher than 4.0,
>   you should provide the version in the call so that the search for the
>   template will find a match. For example, instead of calling
>   `GetProjectTemplate("Extensibility\1033\VSIXProject.zip", "CSharp");`
>   call
>   `GetProjectTemplate("Extensibility\1033\VSIXProject.zip|FrameworkVersion=4.5", "CSharp");`.

So I would expect this to work as you need it to:

```
$dte.Solution.GetProjectTemplate("ConsoleApplication.zip|FrameworkVersion=4.6", "CSharp")
```